# If $|a+b|≤1,$ then $ |a|≤|b|+1.$

Tags: real-analysis, inequality, absolute-value

How can I prove

If $|a+b|≤1,$ then $|a|≤|b|+1$

in real analysis ?

I try to use Triangle inequality

Answer (score 6, accepted):

$|a|=|a+b-b|\le |a+b|+|-b|=|a+b|+|b|\le 1+|b|$

Answer (score 2):

See that it is true: |a|-|b|<|a+b|≤1.

Answer (score 1):

$$|a|-|b|\leq |a+b|\leq1\implies |a|\leq |b|+1$$

You can also remark that $|b|\leq |a|+1$.

Answer (score 1):

We have $|a+b|-|b|\leq |a|$.

Now set $a=x+y$ and $b=-y$

This yields $|x|-|y|\leq |x+y|$

Answer (score -1):

Hint:
$$
a=a+b+(-b).
$$
You should be able to go from here.

Comment: Sorry to write this but you managed to post a misleading hint...

Comment: @Did I hope is less misleading now.

Comment: Now it works. Whether this answer should have been reposted at all, especially by some user with 30k rep, is another story.